# mysql multiple joins counting rows not working

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Here is my query

```
SELECT vj.`id`,`title`,`bill_rate`,`location`, count( vs.job_id ) as total_submissions, 
count( vi.job_id ) as total_interviews
FROM `job` vj 
LEFT JOIN job_submission vs ON vj.`id` = vs.`job_id` 
LEFT JOIN interview vi ON vj.`id` = vi.`job_id` 
WHERE vj.`jobStatus`='2'
GROUP BY vj.id
```

output of the above query is below

[image]

It returns me 12 records from `job` table when I left joins it with `job_submission` then `count( vs.job_id ) as total_submissions` counts correct number of rows but if I use multiple joins like I did in this query to also count number of interviews from another table then the count`total_interviews` column returns me the same values as was returned in the `total_submissions` column.
If I remove `LEFT JOIN job_submission vs ON vj.`id`= vs.`job_id`` then the total_interviews count is counting correct.

I know we can use multiple left joins, can't figure out why this is not working.

thanks in advance for your time

Comment: It's a mite difficult to help in this one without seeing the data. However, I would use `count( distinct vi.id ) as total_interviews` where vi.id is thepk of the interview table.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query